# kivy popup question. How do I get a popup to show up on kivy module?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to have my python and kivy file to open a popup. It says my Boxlayout object has no attribute 'open_popup'

Here is my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.modules import inspector
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup


class CustomPopup(Popup):
    pass


class MPMS(App):
    def build(self):
        inspector.create_inspector(Window, self)

    def show_config_popup(self, popup):
        pass

    def open_popup(self):
        the_popup = CustomPopup()
        the_popup.open()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MPMS()
    app.run()
```

and here is my kivy

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'MPMS'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint: (1, 0.25)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                id: 'screening_button_mainmenu'
                text: 'Screening'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                id: 'configuration_button_mainmenu'
                text: 'Configuration'
                on_press: root.open_popup()

<CustomPopup>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: "The Popup"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'popup has appeared'
```

I tried looking up videos on youtube and whatnot but I couldn't see it helping me because I couldn't apply it to my situation. Please help me out. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your are doing `on_press: root.open_popup()`, and `root` in that case is your `BoxLayout` (the root of that `kv` rule). What you want is

```
on_press: app.open_popup()
```

Because the `open_popup()` method is in your `App`.